# Remove path of subdomain from URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, path, subdomain

I have now put a few hours into this problem, but I can't seem to solve it.

I have 2 Joomla websites (lisettejonkman.nl and tekstbureaulis.nl) both in their own subfolder of a public_html folder, with a .htaccess file to redirect to these websites. The problem is that the URL of these websites shows the path of these two folders (/lisettejonkman.nl and /tekstbureaulis.nl) containing the joomla websites:

> http://tekstbureaulis.nl/tekstbureaulis.nl/anypage

I would like to remove the pathname from this URL to get:

> http://tekstbureaulis.nl/anypage

My .htaccess is in the public_html folder, along with the two folders containing the joomla installations:

```
public_html/.htaccess
public_html/lisettejonkman.nl/(a whole bunch of joomla folders and files)
public_html/tekstbureaulis.nl/(a whole bunch of joomla folders and files)
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
####SUBDOMAINS_HEADER####
RewriteEngine on
#RULE:www,tekstbureaulis.nl,/tekstbureaulis.nl
#RULE:,tekstbureaulis.nl,/tekstbureaulis.nl
#RULE:www,lisettejonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl
#RULE:,lisettejonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl
#RULE:www,lisette-jonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl
#RULE:,lisette-jonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.tekstbureaulis.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tekstbureaulis.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /tekstbureaulis.nl/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^tekstbureaulis.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tekstbureaulis.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /tekstbureaulis.nl/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.lisettejonkman.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/lisettejonkman.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /lisettejonkman.nl/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^lisettejonkman.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/lisettejonkman.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /lisettejonkman.nl/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.lisette-jonkman.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/lisettejonkman.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /lisettejonkman.nl/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^lisette-jonkman.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/lisettejonkman.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)  
####SUBDOMAINS_TAILER####
```

If I try the R=302 method for a single domain:

```
####SUBDOMAINS_HEADER####
RewriteEngine on
#RULE:www,tekstbureaulis.nl,/tekstbureaulis.nl
#RULE:,tekstbureaulis.nl,/tekstbureaulis.nl
#RULE:www,lisettejonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl
#RULE:,lisettejonkman.nl,/lisettejonkman.nl

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.tekstbureaulis.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tekstbureaulis.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /tekstbureaulis.nl/$1 [last]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^tekstbureaulis.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tekstbureaulis.nl/
RewriteRule (.*)            /tekstbureaulis.nl/$1 [last]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?lisettejonkman\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+lisettejonkman\.nl/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
####SUBDOMAINS_TAILER####
```

And I get the following type of errors in the error-log:

```
[Tue Dec 16 22:29:09 2014] [error] [client 82.173.114.125] File does not exist: /home/tekstbureaulis.nl/public_html/administrator
[Tue Dec 16 22:29:11 2014] [error] [client 192.211.49.200] File does not exist: /home/tekstbureaulis.nl/public_html/administrator
```

It seems that it's trying to redirect to a folder (/home) that does not exist, because the order of the path is wrong. But I cannot find this folder in the htaccess code, so I don't really understand...

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Everything is working, but I cannot get the double pathname in the URL to dissappear. I simply don't want the visitor of this website to see the pathname of the different Joomla installations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a redirect in .htaccess

something along the lines of;

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tekstbureaulis.nl/(.*)$ http://www.tekstbureaulis.nl/$1
```

this is just an edit of my index removal redirect and has not been tested.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1
```

Comment: Hey Sean, thanks for the response. I now get an error and a message: "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome. Do I need to remove the others contents of the htaccess file for this to work?